# How to implement Realm in your ios app programmatically?

Tags: ios, uikit, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have an ios app. I need to store two fields in my database realm(Title and image(or path to image). Now my data is storing in struct video but after reloading the app all changes missed. So how can I implement realm in my app?
My code looks :

```
struct Video  {
var image: UIImage
var title : String }

class VideoCell: UITableViewCell {

var videoImageView=UIImageView()
var videoTitleLabel=UILabel()
   
}
required init?(coder:NSCoder){
    fatalError("init(coder :) has not been implemented")
}


func set(video : Video) {
    videoTitleLabel.text = video.title
    videoImageView.image = video.image
    

} 

class VideoListVC:  UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
var tableView=UITableView()
var videos : [Video] = []

var videoImageView=UIImageView()
var videoTitleLabel=UILabel()


struct Cells {
    static let videoCell = "VideoCell"
}


override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    
    title = ""
    videos = fetchData()
    configureTableView()    

}

func configureTableView(){
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setTableViewDelegates()
    
   
    tableView.rowHeight = 290
    tableView.register(VideoCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Cells.videoCell)
    tableView.pin(to:view)



} func setTableViewDelegates(){
    tableView.delegate=self
    tableView.dataSource=self

}
```

extension VideoListVC: UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return videos.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Cells.videoCell) as! VideoCell
    let video = videos[indexPath.row]
    cell.set(video: video)
    
    return cell
    

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return .delete
    
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        videos.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The top section of code *really needs formatting* it's hard to tell what functions go with what classes. Please format it as it appears in XCode so we know what functions go where. e.g. I can see the `VideoCell` class but what does the `required init` go with? What does the `set` function go with?

Comment: This is a good resource for you: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/

Answer (score 1):

1. import realm-swift from github here https://github.com/realm/realm-swift
2. your data should looks somewhat similar to this

```swift
class Video: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: String
    @Persisted var image: Data
    @Persisted var title: String
}
```

I am assuming you want to persist your data after you fetch.

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()

    try realm.write {
        realm.add(video)
    }
} catch {
    assertionFailure("\(error)")
}
```

Not sure if there is a way to persist UIImage. I usually convert it to `Data` when I persist and then initialize the image using the Data when I retrieve.

Comment: Based on the vagueness of the question, this is not a bad answer, and UIImage->Data is the way to go. *-But-* Storing images in Realm is not advised; images can easily be larger than what can be stored in a single field. Realm suggests using another type of online storage for images and keep a reference to that image in Realm. Obviously is varies by use case as if the images are 100k there's no problem at all. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268185/images-storage-performance-react-native-base64-vs-uri-path/67271381#67271381) for details and some options.