# Realm Swift - collection changes listener in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I'm using Realm in my SwiftUI project to store some of my data.
Currently I store there `ConversationObject` and `SettingObject` types.
Each of objects have it's corresponding `Repository`

(e.g. ConversationsRepository):

```
final class ConversationsRepository: ConversationsRepositoryProtocol {
    @Inject private var realmManager: RealmManaging
    
    init() {}
    
    func getConversations() -> AnyPublisher<[Conversation], Error> {
        realmManager.objects(ofType: ConversationObject.self)
            .map { $0.map({ $0.toModel }) }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    [...]
}
```

which utilises `generic RealmManager`

```
class RealmManager: RealmManaging {
    let realm = try? Realm()
    private let realmQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "realmQueue")
    private let updatePolicy: Realm.UpdatePolicy = .modified
    
    private enum RealmError: Error {
        case realmConstructionError
    }
    
    private init() {}
    
    static let shared: RealmManaging = {
        RealmManager()
    }()
    
    func objects<T: Object>(ofType: T.Type) -> AnyPublisher<[T], Error> {
        Future { promise in
            self.realmQueue.async {
                do {
                    let realm = try Realm()
                    
                    if realm.isInWriteTransaction || realm.isPerformingAsynchronousWriteOperations {
                        try realm.commitWrite()
                    }
                    
                    let objects = realm.objects(T.self)
                    
                    promise(Result.success(objects.compactMap { $0 }))
                } catch {
                    promise(Result.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    [...]
}
```

In my project every View

```
struct ChatView: View {
    @StateObject private var chatViewModel: ChatViewModel = ChatViewModel()

    [...]
}
```

has it's ViewModel which manages Repository data and passes it to corresponding View

```
final class ChatViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Inject private var conversationsRepository: ConversationsRepositoryProtocol
    
    @Published var currentConversation: Conversation?
    @Published var conversations: [Conversation] = []
    
    private var cancelBag: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init() {
        fetchConversations()
    }
    
    func fetchConversations() {
        conversationsRepository.getConversations()
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { _ in
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] fetchedConversations in
                guard let self = self,
                      !fetchedConversations.isEmpty else {
                    self?.addNewConversation()
                    return
                }
                
                self.conversations = fetchedConversations
                self.sortConversations()
                self.currentConversation = self.conversations.last
            }
            .store(in: &cancelBag)
    }
}
```

My problem is I have ChatView which displays data for `ConversationObject collection`, but I have **SettingsView** in which I can delete all `ConversationObjects`. Both views' viewmodels use `ConversationRepository` to do their stuff. But I want the data in **ChatViewModel** reload when I delete `ConversationObject` data in **SettingsView**

I want to create observers that I could use in various **ViewModels** so that they could have latest data for my Realm collections and react to changes mutating their views.
I know that I could just simply use **Realm object** inside my **ViewModels** and create `Realm Notification Token` there, but I want to avoid using **Realm object** explicitly in my ViewModels, would prefer to do indirectly by calling some repository function which later calls generic `RealmManager` function, unless it is not possible.

Comment: Realm comes with observers that work great with SwiftUI, just search the documentation for it.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of them however I'm using ViewModels and other structures to manage my data, views only display it and trigger some actions, they do not have reference to realm or whatsoever. As far as I know SwiftUI Realm functionality operates on environment variables created specifically in SwiftUI View which I would try to avoid

Comment: What's more, I do not display SettingObject or ConversationObject directly but I'm mapping it to other structure in ViewModel when fetching it from Realm

Comment: NP maybe someone will decide to help.

Comment: The intent appears to be to override or avoid a core functionality of Realm. There are a *bunch* of downsides to that. e.g. by design, when an observed object or collection changes in a view, the view updates itself automatically. For example `.map { $0.map({ $0.toModel }) }` suppose there are 1 million objects. That one line of code could make the app unstable and crash. Same thing here `.compactMap { $0 }`. High level Swift calls override the lazy-loading nature of Realm. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66603093/modeling-sub-collections-in-mongodb-realm-sync/66643920#66643920)

Comment: Oh and... not using Realm syntax and language features is a LOT more work! Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74544574/how-to-lazy-load-image-from-data-type/74562300#74562300)

Comment: @Jay thanks for your comment.
I will think about refactoring when comes to this double `.map` and `.compactMap`
I have decided to go with Realm's implementation of SwiftUI features. Added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to go with Realm's built-in features that are created especially for SwiftUI. Therefore in every view which ViewModel's should have Realm's data I implemented

```
@ObservedResults(ConversationObject.self) var conversationsObjects
```

It is then passed to ViewModel with modifier

```
.onChange(of: conversationsObjects) { _, updatedConversationsObjects in
    chatViewModel.getConversations(from: updatedConversationsObjects)
}
```

Later, the method `getConversations` converts it from Realm Object to my other structure that is assigned to `@Published var` and this data is displayed on screen

The same technique is applied to **SettingsObjects**, **SettingsView** and **SettingsViewModel** respectively.
By using this approach I was able to get automatically refreshing Realm data I want.