# Using Realm Sync with Atlas increases my app size drastically

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using **Realm** for my application because of it's **offline first** approach. My app will send lots of images to db/Atlas.

I observed that my **app size is getting** increased. I am wondering that it's storing all data including all images locally as well in all devices for offline availability.

So **my question** is when my data size keeps on increasing and suppose it reach 10 Gb of space, will my app be able to handle this and what my app size will be. Will it be 10 Gb? What can I do to handle it and what are the **dos and don't s** to handle it?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Your **app size**? Meaning how much disk space the app occupies? How much memory it uses? Something else? Are you referring to your Realm database size? Storing blob type data such as images in Realm is not generally a good idea - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268185/images-storage-performance-react-native-base64-vs-uri-path/67271381#67271381). You may also be overriding the [lazy-loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) nature of Realm by using high level non-realm functions and/or arrays. Do you have some code to share?

Comment: Thanks Jay. Actually it's the data I want to talk about. It's my mistake in the question. App size is constant, around 43 Mb. But because of the images syncing, Realm database size is increasing. Lazy-loading can be an alternative. Let me come with some proof of concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm is primarily a database that also happens to offer synchronization features. So when you say you're sending lots of images to Atlas, it means you're storing them in the *local* Realm database, which then uploads them to Atlas in the background. One way to reduce your local storage and optimize data usage is to instead upload the images to S3/Azure Blob Storage and only store their urls in Realm/Atlas. I [have a project that does that for C#](https://github.com/nirinchev/realm-lfs), but it's a few hundred lines of code that can easily be ported to another language.

The benefits of doing it that way are threefold:

1. You load/cache images on demand rather than storing them along with your data. There are many libraries (e.g. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)) that handle downloading, caching, and displaying the images.
2. You can use a server-side function to generate thumbnails/different image sizes whenever an image is uploaded, making it faster to display the image on different devices.
3. You can configure/take advantage of CDNs to move the binary data closer to your end users and reduce latency.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. I will bother you later once I am complete with the solution.